# Filter list view on related object fields

Tags: list-view, filters

I'd like to be able to filter list views with related object fields. Something that is easily feasible in reports, however I'd like to be able to do the same for list views. I have noticed in my org this option for contacts - I can filter over account's fields as in the screen.

[image]

Is it possible to make such filters in any other object? I do not want to create additional formula fields and triggers as I have seen in some suggestions. It seems the contact can filter on account's fields without any additional fields in contact.

Answer (score 1):

If it's not there, it is not there. But you can try creating a formula field that will pull a value from parent object and use that in your filter.

Note that in the latest release you can also do inline editing in reports, so there's another good reason to use them in place of list views. that's if the following list view limitations are not convincing enough:

- Record display and search limit = 2000 records
- Limited space for displayed columns
- Inferior exporting options